# How to convert a multiple-line variable containing JSON to single line in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I have below variable in shell

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "projectid234",
  "private_key_id": "aasdadsxzce5",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCiWjA5+xF6gsGC\nOknIL9DOCQpV2LRXYPEKl5+mXuN45vwqh6QvG4lw/Hi7EJhtAn+FQy7+yOQYrw3l\nQ2CpxDotT+PT2OuQ6LVbc/F+SblPlrK3B+8aEMo57PZ+gnwMcQ7+ofPnzC635uUP\npOG0idMTK\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "clinetmail@asdasd3435.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "1234242342341",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/assadjashd.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Like below:

```
export var1='{
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "projectid234",
      "private_key_id": "aasdadsxzce5",
      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCiWjA5+xF6gsGC\nOknIL9DOCQpV2LRXYPEKl5+mXuN45vwqh6QvG4lw/Hi7EJhtAn+FQy7+yOQYrw3l\nQ2CpxDotT+PT2OuQ6LVbc/F+SblPlrK3B+8aEMo57PZ+gnwMcQ7+ofPnzC635uUP\npOG0idMTK\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "clinetmail@asdasd3435.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "1234242342341",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/assadjashd.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }'
```

Now I want to convert it to a single line, what should I do?
I tried various solutions but they didn't work. for instance I used below code which I found but after converting to base64 and decoding it, it just return the first line. would you mind help me?

```
$((echo $var1 | tr -d '\n') | base64)
```

Comment: So your goal is to make the JSON compact to a single line?

Comment: @0stone0 yes exactly

Comment: `echo $var` is very different than `echo "$var"`.  Indeed, `echo $var1` is a reasonable(arguable) way to discard all the newlines.

Comment: I had to do a double-take on this - this was my first thought as well, but then I thought "Won't `echo`ing it without quotes parse out the escape codes?" But no, they are part of the data, just like the double-quote characters themselves, or like an embedded dollar sign would be. I'm always a little wary of unquoted vars, but this looks like maybe a prime example of when they are exactly what you want. I'm still looking for holes in that, but I think William Pursell is right. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're dealing with JSON, I'd recommend a tool like [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), which provides us with the `--compact-output` option and is capable of encoding to Base64 using `@base64`

---

To single-line output

```
jq --compact-output '' <<< "$test"
```

---

To Base64 single-line output

```
jq --compact-output  '@base64' <<< "$test"
```

---

To Base64 single-line output, and decoding with bash

```
jq --compact-output --raw-output '@base64' <<< "$test" | base64 --decode
```

**Note** the `--raw-output` to remove the `""`'s.

---

Local shell example of above lines:

```
$ test='{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "projectid234",
  "private_key_id": "aasdadsxzce5",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCiWjA5+xF6gsGC\nOknIL9DOCQpV2LRXYPEKl5+mXuN45vwqh6QvG4lw/Hi7EJhtAn+FQy7+yOQYrw3l\nQ2CpxDotT+PT2OuQ6LVbc/F+SblPlrK3B+8aEMo57PZ+gnwMcQ7+ofPnzC635uUP\npOG0idMTK\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "clinetmail@asdasd3435.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "1234242342341",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/assadjashd.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}'
$
$ jq --compact-output '' <<< "$test"
{"type":"service_account","project_id":"projectid234","private_key_id":"aasdadsxzce5","private_key":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCiWjA5+xF6gsGC\nOknIL9DOCQpV2LRXYPEKl5+mXuN45vwqh6QvG4lw/Hi7EJhtAn+FQy7+yOQYrw3l\nQ2CpxDotT+PT2OuQ6LVbc/F+SblPlrK3B+8aEMo57PZ+gnwMcQ7+ofPnzC635uUP\npOG0idMTK\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n","client_email":"clinetmail@asdasd3435.iam.gserviceaccount.com","client_id":"1234242342341","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/assadjashd.iam.gserviceaccount.com"}
$
$
$ jq --compact-output '@base64' <<< "$test"
"eyJ0eXBlIjoic2VydmljZV9hY2NvdW50IiwicHJvamVjdF9pZCI6InByb2plY3RpZDIzNCIsInByaXZhdGVfa2V5X2lkIjoiYWFzZGFkc3h6Y2U1IiwicHJpdmF0ZV9rZXkiOiItLS0tLUJFR0lOIFBSSVZBVEUgS0VZLS0tLS1cbk1JSUV2Z0lCQURBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRRUZBQVNDQktnd2dnU2tBZ0VBQW9JQkFRQ2lXakE1K3hGNmdzR0Ncbk9rbklMOURPQ1FwVjJMUlhZUEVLbDUrbVh1TjQ1dndxaDZRdkc0bHcvSGk3RUpodEFuK0ZReTcreU9RWXJ3M2xcblEyQ3B4RG90VCtQVDJPdVE2TFZiYy9GK1NibFBsckszQis4YUVNbzU3UForZ253TWNRNytvZlBuekM2MzV1VVBcbnBPRzBpZE1US1xuLS0tLS1FTkQgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLVxuIiwiY2xpZW50X2VtYWlsIjoiY2xpbmV0bWFpbEBhc2Rhc2QzNDM1LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiMTIzNDI0MjM0MjM0MSIsImF1dGhfdXJpIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tL28vb2F1dGgyL2F1dGgiLCJ0b2tlbl91cmkiOiJodHRwczovL29hdXRoMi5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS90b2tlbiIsImF1dGhfcHJvdmlkZXJfeDUwOV9jZXJ0X3VybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL29hdXRoMi92MS9jZXJ0cyIsImNsaWVudF94NTA5X2NlcnRfdXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vcm9ib3QvdjEvbWV0YWRhdGEveDUwOS9hc3NhZGphc2hkLmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIn0="
$
$
$ jq --compact-output --raw-output '@base64' <<< "$test" | base64 --decode
{"type":"service_account","project_id":"projectid234","private_key_id":"aasdadsxzce5","private_key":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCiWjA5+xF6gsGC\nOknIL9DOCQpV2LRXYPEKl5+mXuN45vwqh6QvG4lw/Hi7EJhtAn+FQy7+yOQYrw3l\nQ2CpxDotT+PT2OuQ6LVbc/F+SblPlrK3B+8aEMo57PZ+gnwMcQ7+ofPnzC635uUP\npOG0idMTK\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n","client_email":"clinetmail@asdasd3435.iam.gserviceaccount.com","client_id":"1234242342341","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/assadjashd.iam.gserviceaccount.com"}%
$
$
```

Comment: can u convert the output to base64 bit and again decode it? when I do it, I am getting only the first line!

Comment: @Amir, the file might have windows line endings aka carriage returns.

Comment: Added another example @Amir!

Comment: @0stone0: thanks for providing more examples, can u check what I am doing wrongly that I am getting base64: invalid input??!
$ export x=$(jq --compact-output '@base64' <<< "$var1")
$ echo $x | base64 -d
base64: invalid input

Comment: Add `--raw-output` to the `jq` command. See the `note` in my answer.

Comment: yeah, `jq` is almost certainly your best option.

Comment: @0stone0 With the use of `@base64` the `--compact-output` flag serves no purpose anymore. Also, in your second example (`jq --compact-output  '@base64' <<< "$test"`) you might want to specifically replace it with `--raw-output` (as you do in the following example) because without it quotes will be printed along (as it is still a JSON-encoded string) which might come unexpected.

Comment: @pmf, thanks, solid points, appreciate it! Will process your feedback when I'm behind my PC.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the use of `base64` but a simple `tr` should work, eg:

```
$ var2=$(echo ${var1} | tr -d '\n')              # ${var1} is not wrapped in double quotes so repetitive white space is squeezed to single spaces

$ echo "${var2}"
{ "type": "service_account", "project_id": "projectid234", "private_key_id": "aasdadsxzce5", "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCiWjA5+xF6gsGC\nOknIL9DOCQpV2LRXYPEKl5+mXuN45vwqh6QvG4lw/Hi7EJhtAn+FQy7+yOQYrw3l\nQ2CpxDotT+PT2OuQ6LVbc/F+SblPlrK3B+8aEMo57PZ+gnwMcQ7+ofPnzC635uUP\npOG0idMTK\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "client_email": "clinetmail@asdasd3435.iam.gserviceaccount.com", "client_id": "1234242342341", "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth", "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs", "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/assadjashd.iam.gserviceaccount.com" }
```

Or as William Pursell pointed out in comments, don't wrap `${var1}` in quotes and you can also eliminate the `od` call:

```
$ var2=$(echo ${var1})                           # the unquoted ${var1} also removes linefeeds so no need for tr

$ echo "${var2}"
{ "type": "service_account", "project_id": "projectid234", "private_key_id": "aasdadsxzce5", "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCiWjA5+xF6gsGC\nOknIL9DOCQpV2LRXYPEKl5+mXuN45vwqh6QvG4lw/Hi7EJhtAn+FQy7+yOQYrw3l\nQ2CpxDotT+PT2OuQ6LVbc/F+SblPlrK3B+8aEMo57PZ+gnwMcQ7+ofPnzC635uUP\npOG0idMTK\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "client_email": "clinetmail@asdasd3435.iam.gserviceaccount.com", "client_id": "1234242342341", "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth", "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs", "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/assadjashd.iam.gserviceaccount.com" }
```

Or if you wish to maintain all the extra white space you can wrap `${var1}` in double quotes before passing to `tr`, eg:

```
$ var2=$(echo "${var1}" | tr -d '\n')            # ${var1} is wrapped in double quotes to maintain all white space

$ echo "${var2}"
{      "type": "service_account",      "project_id": "projectid234",      "private_key_id": "aasdadsxzce5",      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCiWjA5+xF6gsGC\nOknIL9DOCQpV2LRXYPEKl5+mXuN45vwqh6QvG4lw/Hi7EJhtAn+FQy7+yOQYrw3l\nQ2CpxDotT+PT2OuQ6LVbc/F+SblPlrK3B+8aEMo57PZ+gnwMcQ7+ofPnzC635uUP\npOG0idMTK\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",      "client_email": "clinetmail@asdasd3435.iam.gserviceaccount.com",      "client_id": "1234242342341",      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/assadjashd.iam.gserviceaccount.com"    }
```

Comment: I tried to use ur solution but after convert it to base64 and decode it, only the first line return
$ export varwrpped=$(echo "${var2}" | base64)
$ echo $varwrpped | base64 -d
{ "type": "service_account", "project_id": "projectid234"base64: invalid input

Comment: @Amir try `base64 -d -i`

Answer (score 1):

Just as a quick pass, you really should be able to just do this with built-in parameter expansion in `bash`.

The simplest:

```
$: echo "$var1" # this should present it exactly as you saved it
{
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "projectid234",
      "private_key_id": "aasdadsxzce5",
      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCiWjA5+xF6gsGC\nOknIL9DOCQpV2LRXYPEKl5+mXuN45vwqh6QvG4lw/Hi7EJhtAn+FQy7+yOQYrw3l\nQ2CpxDotT+PT2OuQ6LVbc/F+SblPlrK3B+8aEMo57PZ+gnwMcQ7+ofPnzC635uUP\npOG0idMTK\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "clinetmail@asdasd3435.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "1234242342341",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/assadjashd.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }

$: echo "${var1//$'\n'/}" # this should strip out the newlines
{      "type": "service_account",      "project_id": "projectid234",      "private_key_id": "aasdadsxzce5",      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCiWjA5+xF6gsGC\nOknIL9DOCQpV2LRXYPEKl5+mXuN45vwqh6QvG4lw/Hi7EJhtAn+FQy7+yOQYrw3l\nQ2CpxDotT+PT2OuQ6LVbc/F+SblPlrK3B+8aEMo57PZ+gnwMcQ7+ofPnzC635uUP\npOG0idMTK\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",      "client_email": "clinetmail@asdasd3435.iam.gserviceaccount.com",      "client_id": "1234242342341",      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/assadjashd.iam.gserviceaccount.com"    }
```

Assuming you also want to squeeze out extraneous whitespace with a more complex pattern, you might be tempted to use a regex...which won't work, because the parameter parsing actually usesw globbing, but regular expressions *per se*... but try `shopt` for *extended* globbing -

```
$: shopt -s extglob # c.f. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob
$: echo "${var1//$'\n'+( )/}" # remove a newline followed by one or more spaces
{"type": "service_account","project_id": "projectid234","private_key_id": "aasdadsxzce5","private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCiWjA5+xF6gsGC\nOknIL9DOCQpV2LRXYPEKl5+mXuN45vwqh6QvG4lw/Hi7EJhtAn+FQy7+yOQYrw3l\nQ2CpxDotT+PT2OuQ6LVbc/F+SblPlrK3B+8aEMo57PZ+gnwMcQ7+ofPnzC635uUP\npOG0idMTK\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n","client_email": "clinetmail@asdasd3435.iam.gserviceaccount.com","client_id": "1234242342341","auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/assadjashd.iam.gserviceaccount.com"}
```

## edit

There IS whitespace: this changes `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` to `-----BEGINPRIVATEKEY-----`, I just missed it.

> Since you seem to have no whitespaces embedded in your *data* (that I noticed), you could take out the *requirement* for a newline in front of them, and just remove ALL spaces to compact it even more.

```
$: echo "${var1//*($'\n')+( )/}"
{"type":"service_account","project_id":"projectid234","private_key_id":"aasdadsxzce5","private_key":"-----BEGINPRIVATEKEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCiWjA5+xF6gsGC\nOknIL9DOCQpV2LRXYPEKl5+mXuN45vwqh6QvG4lw/Hi7EJhtAn+FQy7+yOQYrw3l\nQ2CpxDotT+PT2OuQ6LVbc/F+SblPlrK3B+8aEMo57PZ+gnwMcQ7+ofPnzC635uUP\npOG0idMTK\n-----ENDPRIVATEKEY-----\n","client_email":"clinetmail@asdasd3435.iam.gserviceaccount.com","client_id":"1234242342341","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/assadjashd.iam.gserviceaccount.com"}
```

Again, this changes `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` to `-----BEGINPRIVATEKEY-----`

> So...in this case, with no embedded spaces, you can achieve the best result without extended globbing at all, by just using POSIX character classes to remove all whitespace, as at the top. :)

```
$: echo "${var1//[[:space:]]/}" # // means global replacement
{"type":"service_account","project_id":"projectid234","private_key_id":"aasdadsxzce5","private_key":"-----BEGINPRIVATEKEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCiWjA5+xF6gsGC\nOknIL9DOCQpV2LRXYPEKl5+mXuN45vwqh6QvG4lw/Hi7EJhtAn+FQy7+yOQYrw3l\nQ2CpxDotT+PT2OuQ6LVbc/F+SblPlrK3B+8aEMo57PZ+gnwMcQ7+ofPnzC635uUP\npOG0idMTK\n-----ENDPRIVATEKEY-----\n","client_email":"clinetmail@asdasd3435.iam.gserviceaccount.com","client_id":"1234242342341","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/assadjashd.iam.gserviceaccount.com"}
```

Comment: There *are* embedded whitespaces: `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: Those are not embedded whitespace - they are embedded escapes that decode *into* whitespace. They are preserved in the output.

Comment: It's really not important because your answer is very clear and helpful, but *yes* there are "embedded whitespaces" in the input, which are not preserved:) This makes your two last proposals not usable in this case (as you explain yourself, and that's why it's not important). Indeed, `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` is transformed to `BEGINPRIVATEKEY` :)

Comment: OMG - LOL! I scanned the key, and missed the headers, even after you *explicitly* showed me the spaces, lol... Thanks. You are absolutely right.